# How can I access Python code from JavaScript in PyQT 5.7?

Tags: javascript, python, qt, pyqt

I used to do it by attaching an object

```
self.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("js_interface", self.jsi)
```

In 5.7 I do:

```
self.page().setWebChannel(self.jsi)
```

But I understandibly get a JavaScript error when I try to access exposed functions:

```
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: js_interface is not defined
```

Googling around I found that I should use qwebchannel.js, but I couldn't find the file or instructions on how to use it anywhere (there was some info, but only in some examples provided when installing QT, not PyQT).

Answer (score 12):

You can include **qwebchannel.js** into html page using the script tag:

```
<script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
```

Then, create a web channel on the python side:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class CallHandler(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot()
    def test(self):
        print('call received')

view = QWebEngineView()
channel = QWebChannel()
handler = CallHandler()
channel.registerObject('handler', handler)
view.page().setWebChannel(channel)
```

JS code that interacts with the web channel:

```
new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function (channel) {
    window.handler = channel.objects.handler;
    window.handler.test();
});
```

Comment: As addition: Please make sure that the `channel`, `handler` and so on are not garbage collected. I was initializing them in in class-method and I could not figure out why it did not work or even segfaulted. The trick was to keep a reference to `channel` and `handler` in the class (e.g. `self.handler = CallHandler()` etc

Comment: @devsnd , I was getting Segmentation fault (core dumped) for weeks  and I was nearly on verge of giving up on the project , you have not Idea how much your comment has helped me. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-standalone-example.html). It contains a useful example (in c++ but easily translatable into python).

First of all, you have to use a websocket to communicate from html to your app and viceversa.

Then you can set up your QWebChannel.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's big drawback, JS cannot directly communicate with Python in PyQT5.9+ like it used to with "addToJavaScriptWindowObject" command.
And using websockets... what if Firewall is heavy and all ports blocked.

I guess I will rely on simple callback (long pooling type from Python to JS checking for changes/commands) method and no QTWebChannel usage.