# How do I merge these two html/javascript files

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-maps, pyqt5

I have this html/javascript file that works fine:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.767367, -111.848007);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  #mapCanvas {

    # width: 1000px;
    width: 102%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -7px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  </style>

      <font size="3" color="black" face="verdana">
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <font size="-10" color="white" face="verdana">
    <!-- <b>Marker status:</b> -->
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <font size="3" color="black" face="verdana">
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It updates the position of the marker when the user moves it. However, I would also like to make appear on the same map some markers, not movable, that correspond to the position of some elements the user inputs. I am including this html/javacsript code in a larger Python function. I have this other javascript code that does the trick, but it doesn't contain the part with the movable marker. In this case, using PyQt5, the user can add markers passed from Python (with `runJavaScript()`) the coordinates of new markers to the function `addMarker()` in the javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.767367, -111.848007);
    var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                               myOptions);
 }

var goldStar = {
    path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
    fillColor: 'yellow',
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 0.1,
    strokeColor: 'gold',
    strokeWeight: 1
  };

function addMarker(lat, lon, city, url) {
    var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        //icon: {path: google.maps.SymbolPath.BACKWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
               // scale: 5},
        icon: goldStar,
        map: map,
        title: city
    });

    newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: url
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
        this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    });
}



</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
''')
```

How can I merge the two files? Basically, how can I have in the same map:

1. A marker that can be moved around the map by the user
2. A bunch of other stable markers that the user inputs through Python (in PyQt5 using `runJavaScript()`)

I can set the list of stable markers in the html page from the beginning, because it is the user to decide their position.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is stopping you from merging the two files?

Comment: What I mean for merging is "merging in a way that the code does what I want" and what's stopping me is probably lack of computational skills, lack of understanding of JS, destiny, bad luck, etc.

Comment: To narrow down the problem a little bit, I would like to add "addMarker" as a function external to "initialize". So that Python can interact with that through runJavaScript(). However, when I tried to merge the 2 codes,  I tried to move "addMarker" around the html file but nowhere it seemed to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is that **all** the js/html code? I assume you must be using this with web-engine in pyqt. Can you show how you are loading the html, and exactly how you are using `runJavaScript()`?

Comment: Yes, that's all. 
Here is the code for the case with fixed markers input through runJavaScript():
https://gist.github.com/carlobianchi89/262e85c356496baf1ae8dc8e2b947e08

Comment: For the other case, with the movable marker, that doesn't interact with Python, the html I posted up here is enough to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `addMarker` doesn't work, is that it cannot access the `map` object created in `initialize`. So you need to make `map` global:

```js
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
...

function addMarker(lat, lon, city, url) {
    var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        map: map,
        title: city
    });
    newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: url
        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
        this['infowindow'].open(map, this);
    });
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.767367, -111.848007);
  // create as a global variable
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  ...
}
```

You should also wait until the page is fully loaded before trying to run any javascript from PyQt. So connect a slot to the `loadFinished` signal and use a single-shot timer to add some extra delay as well (to allow for the google maps control to load):

```
class ShowMap_fun(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.map_ui = Ui_tmy3page()
        self.map_ui.setupUi(self)
        # wait for page to load
        self.map_ui.html_code.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoad)
        self.map_ui.html_code.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('/tmp/test.html'))
        self.map_ui.show_stat.clicked.connect(self.save_fun)
        self.map_ui.html_code.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested)

    def onLoad(self):
        # extra one second delay
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.save_fun)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that worked perfectly!
Additional question: how can I use readJavaScript() again to send the coordinates of the movable marker back to Python?

Comment: @CarloBianchi. Great! I suggest you have a look at [QWebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebchannel.html).

Comment: i actually already did that, but I can't figure out how to use runJavaScript() to extract data from Python.
I'll open another question.

Comment: @CarloBianchi. You can't use `runJavaScript()` to do that. The `QWebChannel` avoids using it altogether. (PS: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42740287/984421) has a working example).

Comment: Oh, I see. I looked at this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780435/return-value-from-javascript-to-pyqt5) and it seemed to be possible. The html of this example doesn't work, though, and I don't know how to adapt it to my case.

How can I do that otherwise?

Comment: @CarloBianchi. The `runJavaScript()` method can execute js code and get a return value using a callback. But there is no equivalent when starting from the javascript side - that is why the web-channel is needed. I am assuming you are talking about events that start within javascript (e.g. from user interaction) that you want to notify to the python side (and possibly also get a response).

Comment: I understand. I saw one example [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Qt-WebChannel-JavaScript-API-td5170173.html) but I can't adapt it to my case.
I'll open another question and look for help.