# How can I directly input HTML code in QtCore.QUrl without referring to file path?

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, qurl, qtwebview

I am building an app in Python using PyQt5 and I am going to freeze it. Therefor I would like to have my python code independent from any local file path.
At some point I am loading an html code with:

```
self.pageXXX.html_code.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(QtCore.QDir.current().filePath("example.html")))
```

How can I change this command so that I can paste the HTML code directly in the `html.load()`?

Something like:

```
    self.pageXXX.html_code.load('''
                                      HTML code
                                ''')
```

Comment: Try `setHtml()` instead of `load()`

Comment: I did, but, since I have a JS code in the HTML and also `qwebchannel.js`, when I use setHtml() the HTML page doesn't load correctly and I get an error message:

`js: Uncaught ReferenceError: QWebChannel is not defined`

Comment: Did u add QWebChannel correctly ? [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42740287/7216865)

Comment: I didn't! Thanks, it works!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Maurice Meyer, the problem was in the way I set `QWebChannel`. I just added

```
<script src="qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"></script>
```

at the top of my HTML code and then:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWebChannel import QWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
```

in my Python code. And the magic happened!